# Django Rest Framework - List all API in Auto generated doc

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm using DRF in order to serve a set of API of my application, my api abstraction layer uses the `ListCreateAPIView` and i have many applications linked to my app, every application, implements an API abstraction level.

Now, what i'm trying to do, is to use the default DRF auto generated doc and "try-it" features that comes as "Battery included" from the framework, and in addition, adding to the breadcrumb "API Root" the list of all api that are implemented in the application without using ANY additional package/library, to be clear:

[image]

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know about the page in the DRF documentation? 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/

Comment: @BrunoA., this page it's not responding to the initial question requirements.

Comment: Apologies, maybe I misunderstood your "requirements" then. Is the "API root" link in the actual page or did you edit the screenshot to add it and demonstrate what you wanted? From the top of my head, I think DRF self-documenting works best with ViewSets rather than views.